# Java automation selenium convert to Pom or factory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help with creating Java automation with Selenium Webdriver to Pom or Pomm factory.
I've read how to create pom without any success.
Please help.
I need help on how to create java automation in pom. **strong text**How to conver it?

```
String baseUrl = "https:amazon.com/";
WebDriver driver;
NavigationPom navigationPom;

private final boolean useFirefoxbrowser = false;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

}

@Before
public void setUp() {

    if (useFirefoxbrowser == false) {
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.addArguments("--width=1240", "--height=720");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    } else {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
}

@Test
public void MacbookTest1() {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("macbook");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/Lenovo']/span/a/div/label/i")).click();
    //Checkboxes
    boolean enabled = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='p_89/Lenovo']/span/a/div/label/i")).isEnabled();
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from creating a simple implementation:

How the Page class might look:

```
class Page {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public Page(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver.driver = driver;
    }

    //Define locators
    
    //Keep elements as By on the top of the class
    private By someElement1 = By.xpath("...");
    private By someElement2 = By.xpath("...");


    //Define page methods
    
    // Examples:
    // public void clickSomeElement()
    // public void fillSomeInput()
    public void doSomeAction() {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(someElement1);
        // do something with the element
        // optionaly wait for something after action
    }

    // Examples:
    // public boolean isPageLoaded()
    // public boolean isSomeElementDisplayed()
    // public String getSomeElementText()
    // public int getSomeElementsCount()
    public Object getSomeData() {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(someElement2);
        // do something with the element and return
    }

}
```

Use pages in your tests, do not work with WebDriver directly.

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    Page page = new Page(driver);
    page.doStep1();
    page.doStep2();
    assertEquals(page.getSomeData(), "Some expected result", "Optional Error message");
}
```

And..

Start from creating a test scenario code, create test steps, which you like to have (methods, which will be underlined in IDE as non-existing), and think about the data, which you like to check.

Then just implement all the non-existing methods you need in Page classes.

Maybe it sounds complicated, but try to start from simple test scenarios and it should become more clear after some practice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If this is a Java project, with Eclipse and Intellij IDEA, you can right click the project and select Convert to Maven. From there, it's fine adjustments (versions) in the POM file.